# Android native calender callback

Tags: android, callback, calendar, android-contentprovider, android-broadcast

Please let me know a way of getting call back for following case from Android Native Calender:

When I am opening programetically native android calender "Add event" screen using **android intent.**

**How to get callback in my application that user pressed "Saved button" or "Cancle button" in android native calender.**

Note: 
I have tried a way of Registered broadcast and Content observer, But Its giving inconsistent callbacks.
I have trien onActivity result, It is getting null intent in return.

Answer (score 0):

Well this not how calendar api works, you won't get direct callbacks the alternate option you can use is Content observer, again you will get inconsistent callbacks more than once but you can use below code snippet to get an idea

```
long lastTimeStampOfCallBack = 0L;
long lastTimeStampOfUpdate = 0L;
long thresholdTime = 10000;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.ContentObserver#onChange(boolean)
 */
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);

    Log.d("content service", "on change called");

    lastTimeStampOfCallBack = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(lastTimeStampOfCallBack - lastTimeStampOfUpdate > thresholdTime){

     //write your code for calendar data

      lastTimeStampOfUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```